# Extension stopped working with Google Chrome manifest v2

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am developing an extension for Google Chrome that was working perfectly, but now stopped working with version 2 of the manifest.

It is giving me the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

popup.js:

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function (aba) {
    link = aba.url;
    titulo = aba.title;
    document.getElementById('mensagem').value = link;
});

function GrabIFrameURL(feedDescription) {
    var regex = new RegExp("iframe(?:.*?)src='(.*?)'", 'g');
    var matches = regex.exec(feedDescription);
    var url = '';
    if (matches.length == 2) {
        url = matches[1];
    }
    var quebra = url.split("/");
    return quebra[4];
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    if (localStorage.nome == '' || localStorage.nome == null || localStorage.email == '' || localStorage.email == null) {
        jQuery('#formulario').hide();
        jQuery('#erros').html('Configure seus dados <a href="options.html" target="_blank">aqui</a>');
    }

    jQuery("#resposta").ajaxStart(function () {
        jQuery(this).html("<img src='img/loading.gif'> <b>Sugestão sendo enviada, aguarde...</b>");
    });

    jQuery('#submit').click(function () {

        var nome = localStorage.nome;
        var email = localStorage.email;
        var mensagem = titulo + "\n\n<br><br>" + link;

        jQuery('#formulario').hide();
        jQuery.post('http://blabloo.com.br/naosalvo/mail.php', {
            nome: nome,
            email: email,
            mensagem: mensagem
        },

        function (data, ajaxStart) {
            jQuery('#resposta').html(data);
            console.log(data);
        });
        return false;
    });

    //Listagem de posts
    var bkg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();

    jQuery('#close').click(function () {
        window.close();
    });

    jQuery('#markeall').click(function () {
        bkg.lidoAll();
        $('.naolido').attr('class', 'lido');
    });

    jQuery.each(bkg.getFeed(), function (id, item) {
        if (item.naolido == '1') 
            lidoClass = 'naolido';
        else 
            lidoClass = 'lido';
        var thumb = GrabIFrameURL(item.description);
        $('#feed').append('<li><a id="' + item.id + '" href="' + item.link + '" class="' + lidoClass + '"><img src="' + $.jYoutube(thumb, 'small') + '" class="' + lidoClass + '"/>' + item.title + '</a></li>');
    });

    $('.naolido').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        klicked = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log(klicked);
        bkg.setLido(klicked);
        $(this).attr('class', 'lido');
        openLink($(this).attr('href'));
    });

    $('.lido').click(function (e) {
        openLink($(this).attr('href'));
    });

    var openLink = function (link) {
        chrome.tabs.create({
            'url': link,
            'selected': true
        });
        window.close();
    }

});
```

I think the problem is in this part of popup.js:

```
jQuery.each(bkg.getFeed(), function (id, item) {
        if (item.naolido == '1') 
            lidoClass = 'naolido';
        else 
            lidoClass = 'lido';
        var thumb = GrabIFrameURL(item.description);
        $('#feed').append('<li><a id="' + item.id + '" href="' + item.link + '" class="' + lidoClass + '"><img src="' + $.jYoutube(thumb, 'small') + '" class="' + lidoClass + '"/>' + item.title + '</a></li>');
});
```

Comment: Well, if that's your entire code then you are missing a closing brace... And, it's generally good practice to use braces in `if-else` statements.

Comment: I used keys, but the error persists.

Comment: Can you provide the full extension, as in a zip folder or crx?

Comment: Follow the .rar: http://www.mediafire.com/?0f7mrjvxtw5u4ad

Comment: I'm not seeing the error... Do you know what line it's on?

Comment: File popup.js line 61. This app should list the links of a feedburner, but is giving error in version V2 manisfest.

Comment: Weird... that's `window.close();`. The problem could be that `window.close()` from  a chrome extension popup is for the _parent_ window. Try `self.close()`.

Comment: The problem (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input        line 1) persists. As I said earlier, I believe the problem is in line 61. I do not understand the relationship with window.close ().

Comment: I still don't see an error, try refreshing your extension and/or using my version of [popup.js](http://pastebin.com/YuEyHg1x)

Comment: Click "inspect element" you will see the error.

Answer (score 1):

You problem is actually in background.js on lines 12 and 20, you set localStorage.items to `''` initially but then try to run a `JSON.parse()` on it later, but it's not JSON data so JSON.parse returns `Unexpected end of input`. And, JSON.parse isn't a function you define but a native browser function so, it shows the error as being on "line 1".

Try defining it as an empty array initially and then "pushing" to it as you are now.

Comment: Can you give me an example code? I'm not very good with jQuery.

Comment: Just set the localStorage items in your setLocalStorage function like this:`emptyArray = []; localStorage.items = JSON.stringify(emptyArray); localStorage.lido = JSON.stringify(emptyArray);`

Comment: You need to reinstall the extension _and_ manually remove the localStorage items (`localStorage.removeItem()`) so that they get re-set.